# Failed to create Android Engine Connected Android Project

Tags: android

I have installed Eclipse (Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 3.7.2) + latest version of Android SDK + ADT Plugin + GPE (Google Plugin for Eclipse). When I created **Android Engine Connected Android Project** I got "Creation of Element Failed  Reason: C:\Android...\tools\lib\proguard.cfg (The system cannot find the file specified)"  and " Creation of element failed.  Reason:  Resource '/myc2dm.project.test-AppEngine/war/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml' already exists.  I repeated the same installations on different PC (Window 7) and got the same problems. I created Android "Hello World" project fopr test and it worked well. Did I use wrong Eclipse version or I miss some configurations? Really apprciate your help, thank you in advance.

Comment: did you update "Android Engine Connected Android" addin in Eclipse? if it will not help copy "proguard.cfg" from some random project to "C:\Android...\tools\lib" and try to create new AEC project

Answer (score 1):

Copy proguard.cfg from another project into the location it's complaining about (/tools/lib).  You will also have to delete all the files from the original project that failed to build all the way - that's the reason for the "already exists" error you are getting.

A default proguard.cfg can be found linked to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6164693/483458

Comment: Thanks Selvin and Hayes... I'll try you both inputs, although I don't have any proguard.cfg fiel yet since my first shot was failed. By the way, don't you think we shoul not get these errors? I can create multiple AEC projects?

Comment: Yes, I finally found a proguard.cfg file, copied it to the lib location, cleaned out old project and re-created a new AEC project. This time, it didn't complain these two prblems. A Big Thank-You to Selvin and Hayes!!!!

Answer (score 1):

What has been mentioned is really a hack not a solution.  We shouldn't have to do this, it should work "out of the box".

Why is this happening now?  At one time I was able to create app engine connected android project without any problems, and now it is complaining about proguard.cfg...did the latest update to android sdk take this file out for some reason?

Creating a new Android project does not need proguard.cfg but app engine connected android project does.